# How to upload image from react hook form to laravel api?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, react-hook-form

I am currently creating a profile photo upload feature on my website. And I was confused when creating the feature, I used react-hook-form I have done this

```
<input {... register ('image')} type = "file" />
```

but when I want to take the filename and upload it, the filelist comes out and I am confused about how to upload it to the api that I made in laravel.

```
0: Files
lastModified: 1611628155852
lastModifiedDate: Tue Jan 26 2021 09:29:15 GMT + 0700 (Western Indonesia Time) {}
name: "142589994_3573526806028659_1790097804780058723_n.jpg"
size: 58342
type: "image / jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

above is the input that comes out when I click submit.

Is there any other way to get it uploaded successfully?